# Make Database as ReadOnly in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to convert the Mongo database as readonly on the primary node and on all other secondary nodes?

Like in SQL Server, we can alter database like this:

```
 alter database set readonly
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be 2 ways to achieve this.

- Connecting to secondary directly instead of primary, not as part of the replica set, then it will behave as read only access.
- Or turn on authentication and create read-only users.

Comment: I liked the first option, the second is not working.. though i create read-only users, am able to insert the documents. Here the authentication is not turned on.. is that the reason?

Comment: Yes, also make the auth as ON